# ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 115076 column 173

Tags: python, json

I have problem to parse json file in python.

my code is here :

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('review_sample.json') as data_file:
data = json.load(data_file)
pprint(data)
```

json file format is here :

```
    {
    "table": "TempTable",
    "rows":
    [
        {
            "comment_id": "R1KLDHE77IOLUM",
            "crawl_time": "2015-07-17 22:55:16",
            "title": "Excellent TV, excellent price... but look out for bugs.",
            "overall_rating": "5",
            "purchase": "Verified Purchase",
            "comment": "This is an excellent TV at an excellent price. For those who say that you can't tell the difference between 4k and ***p, I disagree. I compared this side by side to my *** LG 55' ***p set, and the resolution and sharpness of the image is just no comparison. Can you see an individual pixel from a normal viewing distance on either set? Of course not. But you can see when things start to get fuzzy and pixelated with a large ***p set, and that simply is not an issue with 4K. Picture quality is outstanding but you will want to tweak picture settings - I find that 'Standard' and 'Photo' modes are the best right out of the box, but worth customizing. I also turned off TruMotion, which seemed to be creating some lag when gaming, and is also a bit unsettling for movies and TV (which are usually filmed in 24 and 30 FPS, respectively, rather than 120 FPS TruMotion). 4K playback from Netflix and Amazon Instant Video are superb, as is upscaling from a ***p source. I was surprised how great Battlefield Hardline looked when upscaled to 4K. Overall, WebOS 2.0 is a joy to use, though I'm not a huge fan of the Smart Remote - just clunky to use and not really necessary. I had a bit of a scare when suddenly every 20th vertical row of pixels started bugging out in rainbow colors - see photos. I cycled the power and everything was fine, so I suspect that this was a software bug in the upscaling process (was playing Xbox One at ***p at the time). Will update this review if it happens again. Build quality feels good and the TV looks great - very sleek, slim, and minimal bezels.",
            "site": "amazon",
            "brand": "lg",
            "country_code": "us",
            "product_group_name": "tv",
            "product_name": "smarttv",
            "model_name": "4k",
            "model_code": "*UF7600"
        }
    ]
}
```

if I have a few reviews, it doesn't make the problem. but if I load full json file(a lot of reviews), value error is occured.
The error message is here.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/kaggle/word2vec/server.py", line 11, in <module>
    data = json.load(data_file)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\json\__init__.py", line 291, in load
    **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\json\decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 115076 column 173 (char 8301811)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

please help.

Comment: So the example you show us works but a much larger example doesn't? You could open it in a text editor and look around line 115076 to see if its something obvious like a missing comma. Failing that, remove row items until you are around the 115076 line and test to see if it still fails.

Comment: You could also print out the stuff around the problem area to see if there is something obvious, like, `f = open('review_sample.json', encoding='utf-8'); f.seek(8301811 - 200); print(f.read(300))`. Just do some experimenting to see if you can get enough context to see what the invalid character is.

Comment: @tdelaney `EOF` characters. why use `json` ? How to ignore unreadable character ? Read lines, clear and add to a string variable before `json.loads()`

Comment: @dsgdfg - how do you know its EOF - which isn't a character it just means you've read past the end of the file? And why add a string variable (not sure what that means)? If you hit EOF it means its not a valid JSON file and OP should deal with that issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can NOT json.loads a file handle, you should loads string instead.

I have your content in a.txt

[root@ebs-49393 tmp]# python test.py

{u'table': u'TempTable', u'rows': [{u'comment': u"This is an excellent TV at an excellent price. For those who say that you can't tell the difference between 4k and ***p, I disagree. I compared this side by side to my *** LG 55' ***p set, and the resolution and sharpness of the image is just no comparison. Can you see an individual pixel from a normal viewing distance on either set? Of course not. But you can see when things start to get fuzzy and pixelated with a large ***p set, and that simply is not an issue with 4K. Picture quality is outstanding but you will want to tweak picture settings - I find that 'Standard' and 'Photo' modes are the best right out of the box, but worth customizing. I also turned off TruMotion, which seemed to be creating some lag when gaming, and is also a bit unsettling for movies and TV (which are usually filmed in 24 and 30 FPS, respectively, rather than 120 FPS TruMotion). 4K playback from Netflix and Amazon Instant Video are superb, as is upscaling from a ***p source. I was surprised how great Battlefield Hardline looked when upscaled to 4K. Overall, WebOS 2.0 is a joy to use, though I'm not a huge fan of the Smart Remote - just clunky to use and not really necessary. I had a bit of a scare when suddenly every 20th vertical row of pixels started bugging out in rainbow colors - see photos. I cycled the power and everything was fine, so I suspect that this was a software bug in the upscaling process (was playing Xbox One at ***p at the time). Will update this review if it happens again. Build quality feels good and the TV looks great - very sleek, slim, and minimal bezels.", u'purchase': u'Verified Purchase', u'model_code': u'*UF7600', u'title': u'Excellent TV, excellent price... but look out for bugs.', u'brand': u'lg', u'comment_id': u'R1KLDHE77IOLUM', u'site': u'amazon', u'model_name': u'4k', u'crawl_time': u'2015-07-17 22:55:16', u'country_code': u'us', u'product_group_name': u'tv', u'product_name': u'smarttv', u'overall_rating': u'5'}]}

[root@ebs-49393 tmp]# cat test.py

import json

buf = open('./a.txt').read()

j = json.loads(buf)

print j

Comment: Are you simply saying that OP's example works for you? That is best expressed as a comment.

Comment: no, just showing him how to do it right. as i was saying he called loads with wrong parameter, that's it.

Comment: OP did `json.load` and I haven't seen any edits. And if he did use `loads` then all json files would fail, not just the large ones.